# Navigation not lining up

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with the navigation bar. The image isn't sitting nicely in line with all the other elements, and I can't add margins to the list elements to push them up. It's fine on jsfiddle without the image, and there's no weird margin/dimension issues with the original image itself.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/kf1x3qut/

```
<body>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<a href="index.html"><img src = "img/logo.png" id="logo"></a>
<li><a href="#pt1">about</a></li>
<li><a href="#pt2">software</a></li>
<li><a href="#pt3">contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#pt4">login/sign up</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="pt1">
<img src = "img/cover.png">
</div>

</body>


img{width: 100%;}

.menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #454545}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;}

li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 4%;}

ul{
    float: right;
    width: 100%;}


#logo{
    width: 14%;
    margin: 1% 31% 1% 1%;}
```

Comment: If you provide the full url to the image in the jsfiddle, it might make it easier to debug the problem.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kf1x3qut/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kf1x3qut/1/

Updated your fiddle (I used a random, placeholder image for the logo instead), I added `vertical-align: middle;` on your `#logo` ID to centre the li tags

W3C talk a little bit about what `vertical-aligning` elements does http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ this might be a better article written about `vertical-aligning`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issue I found with your code... check them in below -

```
#logo{
    width: 10%;
    margin: 1% 31% 1% 1%;
}
```

if your div `100%` then `10%` + `31% (right margin)` + `other li's width`.

Is it actually possible? So, take care about them. Hope you can solve it.